# Find the index of N in the sequence of numbers with nondecreasing digits (without reconstructing the sequence)

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics, number-theory

Consider the sequence of all nonnegative integers that have digits in nondecreasing order, i.e., digits sorted from left to right ([A009994](https://oeis.org/A009994) in the OEIS). This sequence starts with 0 and includes numbers like 29, 33 and 112, but not 30, 31, 32 or 105.

Now, given a number N with nondecreasing digits, I need to find its position in the sequence. Alternatively, I need to find how many numbers with nondecreasing digits are smaller than N.

This can be done in O(N) time if we simply generate each number in the sequence until we find N. Furthermore, we can pre-compute the sequence up to some maximum number and then use binary search to find the index in O(log N). But since in my program this computation needs to be repeated thousands of times (inside an inner loop) for different values of N, it would be nice if I had **a more efficient algorithm or even a closed formula to compute the index**.

In case it matters, in my program N is a four-digit number in base 7, i.e., 0 <= N <= 6666<sub>7</sub>.

The [maximum index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) of N in my program is C(7+4-1, 4) - 1 = 10! / 4! / 6! - 1 = 209.

Edit: Since some contributors are emphasizing how good the solutions involving reconstructing the sequence actually are, I want to note that memory usage is important too. I recognize that said solutions aren't terrible, but they certainly seem wasteful. The somewhat similar problem of finding the index of a permutation has [a simple solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) that doesn't require reconstructing the sequence.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: If there *was* a closed-form solution wouldn't you think it would be at the link provided?

Comment: To be clear -- the digits must be "non-decreasing" in base 7?

Comment: Do you understand how little difference there is between O(1) and O(log N) when N<=6666(base 7)?

Comment: 6666 base 7 is only 2400.  Precompute a dict mapping numbers to their index.  Then it is just a lookup in the dict.

Comment: @ScottHunter Some effort is described in the question. The links provided don't deal with the problem of finding the index, this is a specific problem about which I haven't found much information on the internet. In the inner loop there's a big difference between O(1) and O(log N).

Comment: @hugo Yes, the digits must be non-decreasing in base 7. Hopefully a solution for base 10 can be easily adapted to any base, though.

Comment: About the last part of your comment: N is small, so reducing the big O complexity might not crucial to reducing the actual run time. That the whole thing gets repeated 1000's times isn't relevant, you still have N<=6666 in the problem at hand.

Comment: Searching memory thousands of times is slower than doing a few multiplications. Also, memory usage. See my edit for more information.

Comment: I'm asking for help because my solution wasn't fast enough and similar problems have faster solutions that don't use any memory as mentioned. I'm not asking how fast my solution is (I have benchmarks), but thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm not saying searching memory is the best approach, I'm pointing out that reducing the *run time* of your algorithm (which I very well understand you need to do, and I wouldn't question it!) doesn't necessarily mean reducing the *big O complexity* of it -- which is, again, completely orthogonal to the number of times you run the whole thing. Hope that makes sense. I think the problem is too difficult for me, I just needed to point out the false premise. Hope you find a nice and smarter way to do it!

Comment: "reducing the run time of your algorithm doesn't necessarily mean reducing the big O complexity of it" - yes, that makes sense. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I regret even mentioning that N is small for this specific program. Unfortunately people searching for a general solution will stumble on this page and find nothing because the whole discussion was derailed by the size of N.

Comment: fwiw: computing the index of a permutation is easy because the place values don't depend on the digit values. For example, given a permutation of the array `{0,1,2,3}`, the permutation index is `6*X + 2*Y + 1*Z`, where X, Y, Z are adjusted digit values for `array[0]` thru `array[2]`. The place values 6,2,1 are independent of the digit values. And the place values are easy to compute because they are factorials: 1,2,6,24,120... So I don't see any similarity between the index of a permutation, and the problem in the question.

Comment: I may be able to give you some insight into the problem with an example. Consider that you start with a 4-digit number base 7, e.g. 4556. The 4 has a weight of `195`. Now the problem is reduced to a 3 digit number base 3, because the 4 can only be followed by 4,5, or 6. So we adjust the digits by subtracting 4, and find the index of 112 base 3. The leading 1 has a weight of `6`. The problem is reduced to 01 base 2. A leading 0 has no weight, so the problem is reduced to 1 base 2, which has an index of `1`. The final answer is `195+6+1 = 202`.

Comment: All that's left is to figure out a way to compute the weight of the leading digit of an X digit number base Y.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a closed-formula solution expanding on the notion that A009994 is the sequence of combinations with repetitions in lexicographical order.

The solution is summarize by the following Python code:

```
>>> from math import factorial as fact
>>> C = lambda n, k: n>=k and fact(n) // fact(k) // fact(n-k) or 0
>>> I = lambda a, b, c, d: C(10, 4) - C(9-a, 4) - C(8-b, 3) - C(7-c, 2) - C(6-d, 1) - 1
>>> I(0, 0, 0, 0)
0
>>> I(2, 2, 3, 5)
147
>>> I(6, 6, 6, 6)
209
```

**Explanation**

Let's consider the sequence `S` of 3-digit (`K`=3) numbers with digits sorted from left to right in base 10 (`B`=10)

Any number `N` in `S` can be uniquely identified by the count of each digit occurring in it, e.g. if we have 1 occurrence of digit "2" and 2 occurrences of digit "3", then `N` must be "233".

Knowing all digits available, we can use the [stars & bars notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) to represent `N`. In base 10 we have 10 digits available so we need `B`-1=9 bars to separate the slots:

```
|||||||||
```

For `N` = 233, putting the stars in their slots we have:

```
||*|**||||||
```

Now we have a list of `B`-1+`K`=12 objects (9 bars + 3 stars). The positions of the stars in the list (starting from 0) are: (2, 4, 5).

In short, to convert any `N` to its stars & bars 3-tuple representation, we can just add each digit in `N` to its position **in `N` itself**:

```
233 -> (2+0, 3+1, 3+2) -> (2, 4, 5)   (formula I)
```

Again, this 3-tuple uniquely identifies any 3-digit number in base 10 with digits sorted. Conversely, in order to generate any 3-digit number with digits sorted, we could just pick three distinct items from the set of 12 positions {0, 1, 2, ..., 10, 11}. **There's a one-to-one correspondence between `S` and the set `T` of all possible 3-tuples with distinct numbers from 0 to 11.**

The advantage of this representation is that repetition cannot occur since two stars cannot be in the same position. This means that `T` is simply the set of 3-[combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of 12 items.

It's also easy to see that sorting `T` lexicographically is equivalent to sorting `S` numerically.

From this point, we can use the textbook formulas for combinations. This is what I used to find the length of `S`, as mentioned in the question. What I didn't know is that the [formula to find the position of a combination in the list of all possible combinations sorted by ascending order](https://www.dcode.fr/combination-rank) is:

```
I = C(n, k) - C(n-p1, k) - C(n-p2, k-1) - ... - C(n-pk, 1)  (formula II)
```

where:

- C is the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient): C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n-k)!)
- n is the total number of items available (in our case n=B-1+K=12)
- k is the number of items in each combination (k=K=3)
- p1, p2, ..., pk are the items selected (i.e. the items of our 3-tuple)

Finally, plugging formula I inside formula II, we have:

```
I = C(n, k) - C(n-d1, k) - C(n-d2+1, k-1) - ... - C(n-dk+k-1, 1)
```

where d1, d2, ..., dk are the digits of N

Caution: when `N` has the highest digit `B`-1=9, this formula will include C(n, k) where n < k, which, by the definition above, includes the factorial of a negative number, which is not defined. For this reason, we must substitute these terms with zero, since in this case the set of k-combinations of n elements is empty.

And this is the general solution for the question.

Answer (score 0):

> But since in my program this computation needs to be repeated
> thousands of times (inside an inner loop) for different values of N,
> it would be nice if I had a more efficient algorithm

Let's do a sanity check of what it costs you in time not constructing and indexing the sequence.  Let's implement a simple-minded dictionary-based solution:

```
from numpy import base_repr

table = {}

for number in range(int('6666', 7) + 1):
    representation = base_repr(number, base=7)

    a, b, c, d, *rest = representation + '7' * 3

    if b >= a and c >= b and d >= c:
        table[int(representation)] = len(table)
```

Timing one million lookups, on my system this is 15 times faster than your 'general solution'.  But 2/5 of that faster time was spent generating the table.  Let's go a step further, and statically define the table:

```
table = {
    0: 0,
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    3: 3,
    4: 4,
    5: 5,
    # ...
    4666: 204,
    5555: 205,
    5556: 206,
    5566: 207,
    5666: 208,
    6666: 209,
}
```

Doing a million lookups, on my system this is 25 times faster than your 'general solution'.

We've still a way to go towards finding a *closed-formula solution* that is also an *efficient algorithm*.